# Please help me understand these kind of Regular Expressions design

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I've done my research for a while, read some chapters on books about it, and I can't for the life of me resolve these problems. I have read the rules of this kind of algebra.

My teacher teaches this method kinda too barebones, I see everyone include much more intense procedures (things like the sigma and R).

My teacher says there's no "real method" to solve these problems.... which is driving me off a cliff. These problems are translated by me so the grammar will be a bit off, but please bear with me.

For example:

> Find a RE which generates strings that contain "BB" over the alphabet ABC

He arrives at the conclusion:

> $(a\cup b \cup c)^* bb (a\cup b\cup c)^*$

why? how does one do it?

Another one:

> Find a RE that generates strings with the exact same number of B's and A's over ABC
>
> $(ab\cup ba) \cup (ba\cup ab))^*(aa\cup bb)^*$

Why? if anyone has a source which deals with problems like this then please share it as well.

Comment: @saulspatz edited

Comment: Are you sure about the second one?  There is no regular expression that generates all strings with the same number of $A$'s and $B$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your teacher.  There is no recipe for producing regular expressions that generate a particular language.  It's often difficult even to decide whether such a regular expression exists.  You have to study the examples and work the exercises to gain proficiency.

The first problem seems straightforward to me though.  We know the string has to contain $BB$ *somewhere*.  We don't care what, if anything, comes before or after it.  That leads directly to $$(A\cup B\cup C)^*BB(A\cup B\cup C)^*$$ You just have to realize that $(A\cup B\cup C)^*$ matches any string at all over $\{A,B,C\}$.

As to the second problem, I don't understand it.  As I mentioned in a comment, this is not a regular language; there is no regular expression that generates it.

Comment: @ayy_chemixd What are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my side. I may have screwed up the second one. I get what you're saying. Since you mention there's no real way to follow, could you please help me with these 3 problems like you did in the OP? 1) RE that accepts strings of AB exactly twice. 2) ER which contain strings that start with C and contain BB, and finish with A over ABC 3) RE that contains strings which start with C, contain BC only once and finishes with A over ABC

Comment: According to the rules of this site, the comments are not for asking new questions.  If you have another question, you should post another question.  I strongly encourage you to try to do these problems yourself though, instead of asking others to do them for you.

Comment: fair enough, could you share a source where I could learn more about this? Most books and guides online go way over what I'm asking here @saulspatz

Comment: @ayy_chemixd Sorry, it's been many years since I studied this, and I have no idea what's currently available.